# an error occured on file controller (codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined method Dashboard::cek_login()

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_ajax_ci\application\controllers\Dashboard.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_ajax_ci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

---

**Model file :**

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth_model extends CI_Model{
    
    public function cek_login($username)
    {
        $hasil = $this->db->where('username', $username)->limit(1)->get('users');
        if($hasil->num_rows() > 0){
            return $hasil->row();
        } else {
            return array();
        }
    }
    
    public function register($table, $data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert($table, $data);
    }

}
```

**Controller file :**

```html
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->cek_login();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('dashboard');
    }

}
```

Comment: see [Loading a Model](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model)

Comment: have your problem solved or not??

Comment: @KUMAR not yet,  Message: Undefined variable: username

Filename: controllers/Dashboard.php

Line Number: 9

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_ajax_ci\application\controllers\Dashboard.php
Line: 9
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\crud_ajax_ci\index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once

Comment: sorry i am a beginner

Comment: from where `$username` variable is getting input??

Answer (score 0):

For accessing model method you have to load model class First then access Model method.

```
 <?php
    class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {
    
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
    
            $this->load->model('Auth_model');            // Load Model 
            $this->Auth_model->cek_login($username);     // Load Model Method 
    
        }
    
        public function index()
        {
            $this->load->view('dashboard');
        }
    
    }
    ?>
```

**Note:-**

Once loaded Model in Controller, you will access your model methods using an object with the same name as your Model class Name:-

```
$this->load->model('model_name');

$this->model_name->method();
```

**Check here :-**
For Loading Model

https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#loading-a-model